# Creating Hive External table from the result of a Lateral View

Tags: xml, azure, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to create a hive external table and using Lateral View Explode and the result I see is correct. But after creating a table I would like to query the main table without
using the Lateral View.

My code :

```
ADD JAR wasb:///user/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS losApplicantEmployer;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE losApplicantEmployer
(customer array<struct<customer_id:string, type:string>>, employer array<struct<employer_id:string,type:string,employer_name:string,years_employed:int,months_employed:int,create_date:string, update_date:string  >>)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe' 

WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
        "column.xpath.customer" = "/LoanApplications/LoanApplication[@deal_type='REQUESTED']/LoanApplicationStates/LoanApplicationState/Customers/Customer",
        "column.xpath.employer" = "/LoanApplications/LoanApplication[@deal_type='REQUESTED']/LoanApplicationStates/LoanApplicationState/Customers/Customer/Employers/Employer"
        )

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

LOCATION'wasb://glshadoopd3@glsllcteststorage1.blob.core.windows.net/Safe/2016/05/12'

TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start"="<LoanApplications xmlns","xmlinput.end"="</LoanApplications>" );  

select exp_cust.customer_id, exp_cust.type, exp_emp.employer_id, exp_emp.type, exp_emp.employer_name, exp_emp.years_employed, exp_emp.months_employed, exp_emp.create_date, exp_emp.update_date
from losApplicantEmployer 
lateral view explode(customer) exp_customer  as exp_cust
lateral view explode(employer) exp_employer as exp_emp;
```

I want to save the result of the above code as a table. So that I can use it for querying. Please let me know how ?

I don't want to use Lateral View Explode, every time I want to view the result. So I felt storing the whole result in a new table would be ideal. AS  the table losApplicantEmployer is just an array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the results using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT:

```
CREATE TABLE exploded_table AS SELECT exp_cust.customer_id,    
     exp_cust.type, exp_emp.employer_id, exp_emp.type, 
     exp_emp.employer_name, exp_emp.years_employed, 
     exp_emp.months_employed, exp_emp.create_date, 
     exp_emp.update_date
FROM losApplicantEmployer 
   lateral view explode(customer) exp_customer  as exp_cust
   lateral view explode(employer) exp_employer as exp_emp;
```

Comment: But I am looking for an External Table

Comment: and CTAS doesn't support External Tables

Comment: After you create the table you can use ALTER TABLE <table> SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE') (all capital or it won't work)

Comment: I wrote the query to load into internal table but didn't knew we can convert an internal to external. Thanks for it! V up

Can you take a look at this if you can answer this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331487/part-of-filename-as-a-column-in-hive-table