# Part of Filename as a column in Hive Table

Tags: regex, azure, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to get the first part of my filename as a column in my Hive Table

```
My filename is : 20151102114450.46400_Always_1446482638967.xml
```

I wrote a query (below query) using regex in Hive of Microsoft Azure to get the first part of it i.e., 20151102114450

But when I run query I am getting the output as 20151102164358

```
select CAST(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(CAST(CAST(regexp_replace(split(INPUT__FILE__NAME,'[_]')[2],'.xml','') AS BIGINT) as TimeStamp),':',''),'-',''),' ','') AS BIGINT) as VERSION
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong and what needs to be corrected ?

Comment: In cloudera website I read :  Casting an integer value N to TIMESTAMP produces a value that is N seconds past the start of the epoch date (January 1, 1970). What should I do to get the exact filename ?

Comment: try `regexp_replace(TRIM(split(INPUT__FILE__NAME, ':')[1]), "\..*", "")` to extraxt the value

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in Cloudera, hopefully it should work in Azure as well.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_extract('20151102114450.46400_Always_1446482638967.xml','^(.*?)\\.'),'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss');

2015-Nov-02 11:44:50
Time taken: 19.644 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Another option:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(split('20151102114450.46400_Always_1446482638967.xml','\\.')[0],'yyyyMMddHHmmss'),'yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```